# How can I print "\n" using exec()?

Tags: python-3.x

```
ab = open("bonj.txt","w")

exec(f'''print("Hi I'm Mark\n", file=ab)
print("\tToday I'm tired", file=ab)
''')

ab.close()
```

I would absolutely need to use `exec()` to print some informations on a txt doc. The problem is that when I use `exec()`, I lost the possibility of put newlines or tabs on my text, and I dont understand why, could you help me ?

This is the error message that I receive : "`SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"`

Answer (score 0):

You just need to escape `\n` and `\t` properly

```py
ab = open("bonj.txt","w")

exec(f'''print("Hi I'm Mark\\n", file=ab)
print("\\tToday I'm tired", file=ab)
''')

ab.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to prevent python from interpreting the `\n` early.

This can be done by specifying the string as a raw string, using the `r` prefix:

```py
ab = open("bonj.txt","w")
exec(rf'''print("Hi I'm Mark\n", file=ab)
print("\tToday I'm tired", file=ab)
''')
ab.close()
```

Anyway, using `exec` is odd there, you would rather try to see if you can write your code as something like:

```py
lines = ["Hi I'm Mark\n", "\tToday I'm tired"]
with open("bonj.txt", "w") as f:                                                                                                                                                                                 
    f.write("\n".join(lines))
```

Note that you need to use `"\n".join` to obtain the same result as with `print` because `print` adds a newline by default ([see its `end="\n"` argument](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/functions.html#print)).

Also, when handling files, using the context manager syntax (`with open ...`) is good practice.